# Simply using past participle. Is it right?

Tags: grammar, past-participles, conversation, conversational-deletion

I was having a conversation with one of my friends.
And then he started talking about someone I didn't want to talk about.
So I said, "Forget him".
He replied, "Forgotten".

Huh? Like really what does that even mean?
Does it make sense?

Comment: I think this  is a conversation deletion. "Forget him" "(he is) forgotten"

Comment: Ohh, I found it. See [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask/66994#66994)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very normal reply when someone follows what you said. Take an example:

> Now onward, you will not make that mistake *~ Done!*

Here, 'Done' means the person followed the instruction.

In your case, you asked your friend to 'forget', and he said 'forgotten' which is equal to 'Okay, done!'

Such replies are in past participle and most of the times it's just 'done'. But, I have heard a few replying with past participle.

Example:

> Book the tickets ~ *Booked!*

Comment: What if he had replied he(thay guy) is forgotten

Comment: Then it becomes a complete answer...not the short one that we are talking about! In the example I gave, it is actually, "Yes, the tickets are booked!" Nevertheless, *'he is forgotten' has an all different meaning! The complete sentence answered should be -'Okay, I forgot'!

Comment: I aint a native speaker so could you pleasr explain what would he is forgotten mean? 

Comment: *He is forgotten* does not include 'I', which is the main concern here. You were surprised because your friend replied merely with a past participle. A short answer especially in an informal conversation would include just a word or two. "Book my tickets ~ Booked"; "Complete the chapter ~ Completed!' If you simply say 'he is forgotten' the question may come 'he is forgotten by *whom?*'

Comment: What if they write he is forgotten by me . But that would sound way too awkward . Wont it?

Comment: @MaulikV of course he is forgotten by the speaker.